# FullCalendar not honoring specified timezone

Tags: fullcalendar

I am trying to display an event in America/New_York time in FullCalendar. I can get a pop-up to display the correct date/time, but FullCalendar modifies the start and end to the local time zone regardless of my settings.

As an example, I have an event set for 12am June 30, and when I adjust my local time zone to central time, I see in the console that the "start" is modified to 11pm June 29. Thoughts? Thank you!

```
function(result, event){
 if (event.status) {
  var rightNow  = moment.tz("America/New_York");
  $.each(result,function(){
    this.start = moment.tz(this.Event_Time__c, "America/New_York");
    this.StartDate = this.start;
    this.end = moment.tz(this.Event_Time__c, "America/New_York");
    this.EndDate = this.end;
    this.Status = this.Event_Display_Status__c;
    var day = moment.tz(this.Event_Time__c, "America/New_York").format("DD");
    var isWeekend = (day == 6) || (day == 0);    // 6 = Saturday, 0 = Sunday
    var isPast = (rightNow > moment.tz(this.Event_Time__c, "America/New_York"));
    this.isPast = isPast;
    if ( isPast ) {
        this.Event_Display_Status__c = 'Event Passed';
        this.Status = 'Event Passed';
    }
    resultOut.push(this);
  });
  initFullCalendar(resultOut);
 }
 else{
   alert(event.message);
 } 
}

function initFullCalendar(calendarEntries){
    $('#calendarx').empty();
    $('#calendarx').fullCalendar({
        timezone: 'America/New_York',
        editable: false,
        weekends: true,
        eventSources: [{
                events: calendarEntries
        }] 
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your initialization, set the following option:

```
{ timezone: "local" }
```

This does not mean local to the computer, but rather local to the Date Object  provided.

**On the data coming in, set ensure the offset is provided like so:**

```
{ title: "event1", start: "2017-06-28T15:00:00-04:00" }
```

For **America/New_York** it should be -04:00 or -05:00 depending on Daylight Savings and exact location.

Another trick is to provide a Date without any offset at all ("2017-06-28T15:00:00"), then set your timezone ini option to:

```
{ timezone: "America/New_York" }
```

See more at: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timezone/timezone/